# Array inside of Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to have object inside of an Array and Iterate to access Objects one by one.
Please help to solve this.

```
var mainVals = [{id:1,value:[{},{}]},{id:2,value:[{},{}]}];
var hubVals  = [{id:1,value:[{},{}]},{id:2,value:[{},{}]}];

var posit = {1:mainVals,2:hubVals};

  for (var i = 1;i <= 2;i++)
         {
             var obj = posit.i;       
             alert("obj:"+obj); // which gives undefined
         }
```

Comment: use *bracket notation*: `posit[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use square-bracket notation when the property you're wanting to read is dynamic:

```
var obj = posit[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be something like this, since you have two arrays inside of each other:

```
var mainVals = [{id:1,value:[{},{}]},{id:2,value:[{},{}]}];
var hubVals  = [{id:1,value:[{},{}]},{id:2,value:[{},{}]}];
var posit = {1:mainVals,2:hubVals};

for (var i = 1;i <= 2;i++)
     { 
        for(var j = 0; j <= 1; ++j){
           var obj = posit[i][j];       
           alert("obj:"+obj); 
        }
     }
```